# WebStorm ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, html, webstorm

So I got this error when compiling in WebStorm:

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { $(function () {
>
> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

It seems like jQuery isn't loading properly. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="AlexTypescript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="BtnBC">
            Change BC
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my function:

```
$(function () {
    $("#BtnBC").on("click", function () {
        $("body").css("background-color", "black");
    });
});
```

I created a simple button to check if it is functional at all. It is. I just get an error message when compiling in WebStorm.

What I did so far:

```
1) Clean installation of the IDE, nodejs, modules etc.
2) Checking the referenced path of jQuery and that it is loaded before the .js file
3) Referencing a local jQuery installation as well as the CDN
4) Writing jQuery instead of $
```

I'm fairly new to coding, so I would really appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change, dollar sign(`$`) just alias to `jQuery`, other frameworks and libraries can use `$`.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#BtnBC").on("click", function () {
            $("body").css("background-color", "black");
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="AlexTypescript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="BtnBC">
            Change BC
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same outcome:
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: @Captain i created code snippet with this code and he works

Comment: Your code does indeed work. So does mine when I load the website and press the button. The problem I'm facing is, that Webstorm throws an error message at me when I try to compile the code in the IDE itself and I don't know why.

Comment: You using type script ? Compile ?

Comment: Yes I'm coding in a typescript file and I use node.js to compile the transpiled javascript file.